# Slow responding keyboard Windows XP

Tags: windows, keyboard

The keyboard response is normal in the Windows login screen, but is very slow while inside Windows. The problem occures at all times, in all programs.

The problem is not sticky keys or filter keys.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My only paranoid idea might be that a malicious keylogger is running.  If it has a hook which takes a non-trivial amount of time to do processing(such as logging to a file or even sending across the network), then it will create a delay in keystroke processing.  I would suggest running a scan with something like Malware Bytes: www.malwarebytes.org

Edit: Consider booting into safe mode to see if the issue is still present.  If it goes away in safe mode then you know it is probably something running at startup, such as a windows service(a background program), or driver.

If so, use Run->msconfig and disable one item under SErvice or Startup tabs, reboot, test keyboard, disable a different service, reboot, test, etc.  Using the process of elimination you hopefully can determine the problem service or startup program, if that is the issue.

Comment: I don't know if testing each service one by one is the ideal solution. If you test half of all services and startup items at once, you can isolate the problem to half of the remaining services on each boot. Say you are running 16 services. Instead of requiring an average of 8 boots (50% chance it's in the first 12), you'll be able to definitively find the problem in 4 boots. This method could save a lot of time. Assuming, of course, that it's only 1 service or startup program causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you!! The problem was solved when I disabled one of the elements under the Startup tab :)